# No rule to make target

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make QT application using C++ language which will record the video from analogue camera. so I included the `videoInput.h` and `videoInput.lib` files in my project but when i am trying to run the my project then the following error occurs.
the error is:

**mingw32-make[1]:** `No rule to make target path/to/videoInputd.lib', needed by 'debug\test.exe'.  Stop.`

please give me the solution.
thanks for help.

Thanks for your reply. I already added LIBS.

**My .pro file is**

```
QT += core gui
QT += widgets
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    ../../../"Qt Projects/Test projects/test" \
    videoInput.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += E:\\ImageProcessing\\opencv_cmake_binaries\\install\\include
LIBS += -LE:\\ImageProcessing\\opencv_cmake_binaries\\install\\lib \
    -lopencv_core244.dll \
    -lopencv_highgui244.dll \
    -lopencv_imgproc244.dll \
    -lopencv_features2d244.dll \
    -lopencv_calib3d244.dll



win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -lvideoInput
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -lvideoInputd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../"Qt Projects/Test projects/test/videoInput"
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../"Qt Projects/Test projects/test/videoInput"

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/videoInput.lib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/videoInputd.lib
```

**end of .pro file.**
and I changed the build mode to release mode and then try to run then new error comes. The error is

```
error: redefinition of 'bool comInit'

error: 'bool comInit' previously declared here
static bool comInit;

error: redefinition of 'class videoInput'
class videoInput{

error: previous definition of 'class videoInput'
class videoInput{
```

These four errors are in `videoinput.h` file the compiler shows me like this.
And I know the file name is `videoInput.h` but compile output shows me that `videoInputd.lib`, needed by `debug\test.exe`

Comment: From your error description you try to comile an application, which links to a library videoInput. But try to include videoInputd.lib, so a debug version of videoInput. You cannot include a lib file (in INCLUDEPATH) or a library header in (HEADERS), you can only use ``LIBS += -L/path/to/lib -lvideoInput`` directive for the library, ``#include <videoInput.h`` in code and ``INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/libheader``

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

How can i get videoInputd.lib file?
I have already try to find that file in my project folder but i can't get it.

Comment: @user2865434 you need to know where it is. I have a feeling it's part of OpenCV, but my crystal ball is foggy today. In case I have succesfully seen your intent through the fog, I'd suggest installing OpenCV.

Comment: You cannot have videoInputd.lib as long as you do not compile it yourself or get a debug copy somewhere. Just link to non debugversion using ``LIBS`` directive

Comment: thanks you. 
I have install openCV and i have made some project using visual studio with openCV and QT with openCV. I am using QT for GUI purpose. My this project require addition library so i included require library but still i am getting this error.So i need the help.

Answer (score 1):

Do as **Sebastian** tells (add `videoInput.lib` to `LIBS`) and switch build mode to release, since you have only release version of this library (`videoInput.lib`, not `videoInputd.lib`).

Comment: Have you switched build mode to `release`?

Comment: Yes, I changed the build mode to release mode and then try to run then new error comes. The error is

error: redefinition of 'bool comInit'

error: 'bool comInit' previously declared here static bool comInit;

error: redefinition of 'class videoInput' class videoInput{

error: previous definition of 'class videoInput' class videoInput{

These four error is in videoinput.h file the compiler shows me like this. And I know the file name is videoInput.h but compile output shows me that "videoInputd.lib', needed by 'debug\test.exe"

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. When I was trying to include videoInput.lib file in Qt creator, at that time it was displayed above mention error.
So I used qt-vs-addin which is available here. [qt-vs-addin](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

I designed GUI in qt-vs-addin using visual studio 2010 for my application and include videoInput.lib file in visual studio 2010 and now my application is ready. This will be helpful for someone.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

I had similare problem "No tule ro mske tsrgrt. Th rrason was syntax error like

testwx:($(OBJS)....  Check your syntax line by line